# .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count does not return to a correct visible row count

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to filter data that I need so that I can copy and paste into different workbook.

There is no problem with the filter, but the Count return me wrong number of visible rows.

```
Count1 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

I have also tried 
`Count1 = Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count`,but it is giving me error.

```
Sub ListForeignTrans()
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim CoName As Range
Dim Count1 As Long


Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List Foreign Trans")

Set Rng = wsDest.Range("E2")   'To be use in the directory

Set CoName = wsDest.Range("E1") 'To be use in the directory

'Open workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
  "\\172.17.10.134\Finance Tower\0042_Witholding Tax\" & CoName & "\" & Rng & "\" & CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX"

'Filter

With Workbooks(CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>MYR" _
    , Criteria2:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd
.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="<>0.00"
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<> "
Count1 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count 'Count Row

'If only 1 row close workbook, else proceed to copy from the workbook open by previous step to current workbook.
If Count1 = 1 Then GoTo Line1 Else
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks(CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    wsCopy.Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy _
    wsDest.Range("Q" & lDestLastRow)
End With

Line1:
'Close Workbook
Workbooks(CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

There should be 3 rows. But the result keep giving me 1 rows.

Comment: You're running SpecialCells on a single cell

Comment: @Tim Williams How should I solve this? Put Range in front of .SpecialCells?

Comment: Try `.CurrentRegion` after `.Range("a1")`

Comment: @TimWilliams I have tried it, but it count more than 3 line. Thank you for your suggestion and I have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, whereby added these line:

```
Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
Count1 = Rng1.Columns(2). _
   SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

Below is the full code:

```
Sub ListForeignTrans()
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim CoName As Range
Dim Count1 As Long


Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List Foreign Trans")

Set Rng = wsDest.Range("E2")   'To be use in the directory

Set CoName = wsDest.Range("E1") 'To be use in the directory

' List of Foreign Trans

'Open workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"\\172.17.10.134\Finance Tower\0042_Witholding Tax\" & CoName & "\" & Rng & "\" & CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX"

'Filter

With Workbooks(CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>MYR" _
    , Criteria2:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd
.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="<>0.00"
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<> "
Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
Count1 = Rng1.Columns(2). _
   SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count


'If only 1 row close workbook, else proceed to copy from the workbook open by previous step to current workbook.
If Count1 = 1 Then GoTo Line1 Else
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks(CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    wsCopy.Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy _
    wsDest.Range("Q" & lDestLastRow)
End With

Line1:
'Close Workbook
Workbooks(CoName & " Exp GL " & Rng & ".XLSX").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```